# Filetransfer Upload error code 3 in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

when i am upload image with Filetransfer then i get error code 3 in only ios but in android it works fine
My code is below..

```
postUploadProfile(imageData) {
    this.httpService.showLoading();
      let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      }

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        fileTransfer.upload(imageData,this.API_URL, options)
       .then((data) => {
         // success
         this.httpService.hideLoading();

       }, (err) => {
           this.httpService.hideLoading();

         console.log('filetransfer error: ',err);
       })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it works

```
   let options = new FileUploadOptions();
   // this maybe not your case options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.headers = {
          Connection: "close"
       };
```

Comment: i try with
    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
      }
    options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {
      Connection: "close"
   };

but not works

Comment: Error 3 is : FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR. So the error is about the connection, you can't connect via iOs...Let me think some solution

Comment: Ok please check something and tell me what a solution of above problem

Comment: have you checked something?

Comment: Can you give us the complete error code? Console.log(err) in the catch

Comment: body: "{\"Message\":\"An error has occurred.\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"Object reference not set to an instance of a…"

code: 3

exception: null

http_status: 500

source: "file:///Users/crestmac-2/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/26D4FCB5-5AEA-45F5-BCF3-1BCD2C8D59BE/data/Containers/Data/Application/5705B…"

target: "http:......."